# Can traditional water gilding be used with leaves other than gold and silver?

Tags: gilding

Is it possible to gild with imitation, or other than gold and silver, leaves using traditional water gilding? If not, why?

Also, why is it not possible to burnish (using agate stone) when using imitation leaves?

Answer (score -3):

Traditional water gilding is typically done using genuine gold or silver leaves.

While it is possible to use imitation leaves for gilding, the may not yield the same result as genuine gold or silver. (imitation leaves are made from materials like brass or aluminum)

Imitation leaves may end up with some minor differences in color, sheen or texture which may affect the final result.